# JQuery CSS setter not working in webkit when setting column-count property

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have an HTML `ul` that I generate dynamically using JavaScript. After I generate it, I set the style on said `ul` using JQuery's `$('#id').css('property',value)` method. This is what the code in question looks like:

```
$('#actionSpace #datasetContent')
   .css('-moz-column-count',this.content.length)
   .css('-webkit-column-count',this.content.length)
   .css('column-count',this.content.length)
   .css('width',this.content.length*150 + 'px');
```

Essentially, I set 3 different `column-count` properties - once for regular css, once for css in the -moz domain, and once for css in the -webkit domain, and then I also set the `width` property.

This code works just fine in Firefox - the css for the `ul` element with an id of `datasetContent` updates just fine.

However, when I run this in webkit (either Safari or Chrome), this stops working. What's bizarre is that the `width` property (the very last thing I set in that long line of css above) sets properly, but none of the other properties get set. If I change them manually within Chrome's inspector, the site updates just fine. However, of course, I cannot reasonably expect users of my site to manually tinker around with CSS on my page to make it look good :)

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this problem?

**UPDATE** I've tried switching the `ul` to a `div`, and that didn't make a difference at all. The issue is specifically just JQuery CSS & the column-count properties. Perhaps this is something to bring up directly to the folks over at JQuery? I will wait and see if there are any responses here, and if not, I will find the appropriate channel there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered applying your CSS using a single `.css({ // array })` rather than chaining `.css(property, value)`? As you've written it above, it would make sense that your styles would work in Firefox because `-moz-column-count` was correctly applied, but I'm not sure the two consecutive uses of .css() can be chained like that. This doesn't throw an error in Chrome Dev Tools?

I would think

```
$('#actionSpace #datasetContent').css({
  '-moz-column-count': this.content.length,
  '-webkit-column-count': this.content.length,
  'column-count': this.content.length,
  'width': this.content.length * 150 + 'px' 
});
```

might work better.